# JavaFx: Animating from loop, all animations happen in one go

Tags: loops, sorting, animation, javafx, bubble-sort

I am working on a sorting application, which shows animation for bubble sort for a static array.

```
int arr[] ={6,5,3,2,4,1};
```

The problem which I am facing is, 
When I call the animateCircle function from the bubble sort function, all the animations( the multiple transitions that should happen take place in one go ). I have tried using SequenceTransition, ParallelTransition, PauseTransition. But I still can't make the program to pause while the swap animation takes place.

animateCircle function

```
private void animateCircle(Circle fromC, Circle toC, Double fromD, Double toD){

    TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition();
    translateTransition.setNode(fromC);
    translateTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    translateTransition.setToX(toD);

    TranslateTransition translateTransition2 = new TranslateTransition();
    translateTransition2.setNode(toC);
    translateTransition2.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    translateTransition2.setToX(fromD);

    //translateTransition.play();

    //pauseTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(5));

    parallelTransition = new ParallelTransition(translateTransition, translateTransition2);

    //seq = new SequentialTransition(parallelTransition, pauseTransition);

// pauseDelay++;
//        translateTransition.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
//
//            @Override
//            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
//              //translateTransition2.play();
//              System.out.println("Done");
//            }
//        });

//        return true;


    parallelTransition.setOnFinished((ActionEvent e) -> {

        pauseTransition.play();
        System.out.println("IN !!");

    });

    parallelTransition.play();

}
```

The other ways that I tried are commented.

bubbleSort function

```
void bubbleSort(int[] arr,Circle[] circleArray, double[] circleX, Label[] labelArray, double[] labelX) {  
    int n = arr.length;  
    int temp = 0;
    Circle tempC;
    Label tempL;
    double tempD;
     for(int i=0; i < n; i++){  
             for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
                      if(arr[j-1] > arr[j]){ 
                             System.out.println(j-1 + " " + j);
                             temp = arr[j-1];  
                             arr[j-1] = arr[j];  
                             arr[j] = temp;  


                             //System.out.println(circleArray[j-1] +" "+ circleArray[j] + " "+ circleX[j-1] +" "+ circleX[j]);
                             animateCircle(circleArray[j-1], circleArray[j], circleX[j-1], circleX[j]);
                             //animateLabel(labelArray[j-1], labelArray[j], labelX[j-1], labelX[j]);                                 

                             tempC = circleArray[j-1];  
                             circleArray[j-1] = circleArray[j];  
                             circleArray[j] = tempC;

                             tempL = labelArray[j-1];  
                             labelArray[j-1] = labelArray[j];  
                             labelArray[j] = tempL;

                             tempD = circleX[j-1];  
                             circleX[j-1] = circleX[j];  
                             circleX[j] = tempD;

                             tempD = labelX[j-1];  
                             labelX[j-1] = labelX[j];  
                             labelX[j] = tempD;                                                                                              

                             System.out.println("After " + arr[j-1] + " " + arr[j]);
                     }  

             }  
     }  

}
```

[image: Before Sort]

[image: After Swap]

Comment: All animations start at the same time because you call them in loop. You have to call next `animateCircle()` on previous animation finish.

Comment: @MBec Now i understand the problem, but the thing is, call to animateCircle() second time should be when the condition if(arr[j-1] > arr[j]) (for bubble sort) is met and not right after the first animation finishes.